# Discrete math predicate logic - which of my answers are correct?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

Let $F(x)$ be the predicate “x is a frog”, $T(x)$ be “x has a long tongue”, and $J(x)$ be the predicate “x likes to jump”. The universe of discourse is all animals.

I'm asked to write: 
Every frog has a long tongue and likes to jump.

I came up with two answers and I am struggling to figure out which one of them would be the correct one (assuming that any of them are correct). I was wondering if someone could distinguish the difference between the two.

1. $\forall x(F(x)\wedge T(x)\wedge J(x))$
2. $\forall x(F(x) \to (T(x)\wedge J(x)))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one is correct: **if** an animal is a frog **then** it has a long tongue **and** likes to jump.

The first one says that every animal is a frog **and** has a long tongue **and** likes to jump.